# Fit 4 divs inside each 2 divs which are aligned left and right

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm developing a little application using Angular 2 for somebody whose doing an experiment, and so I'm trying to fit 4 divs, each containing an image, into each 2 divs.

For some reason, all the divs (containing the images) are aligned one above the other, instead of one next to each other and only going down one row in case of wrapping. I'm expecting the `guesser` and `describer` divs to fit in the designated area: `guesser` left of the vertical divider and `describer` right to the vertical divider, and both above the horizontal divider, but they don't seem to fill the width of the area, and overflow vertically past the horizontal divider.

How the website currently looks
[image: An image of how the website currently looks]

What I'm expecting the website to look (I edited this using Paint, it's just for illustration)
[image: An image of what I'm expecting the website to look]

And this is my component's HTML and CSS:

```css
div.describer {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
}

div.describer div.container {
    margin: 1em;
}

div.describer div.container img.blocked {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

div.describer div.container img.target {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

div.guesser {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
}

div.guesser div.container {
    margin: 1em;
}

div.guesser div.container.blocked {
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.guesser div.container.blocked img.blocked {
    opacity: 0;
}

div.guesser div.container img.selected {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 3;
}

div.vertical-divider {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 20%;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

hr.horizontal-divider {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 19%;
}

div.commands-container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="describer">
    <h3>Describer</h3>
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let icon of icons">
        <img src="assets/icons/{{trialNum+1}}/{{icon}}" [ngClass]="{blocked: icon == blockedIcon, target: icon == targetIcon}">
        <p *ngIf="icon == blockedIcon">Blocked</p>
        <p *ngIf="icon == targetIcon">Target</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vertical-divider"></div>
<div class="guesser">
    <h3>Guesser</h3>
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let icon of icons" [ngClass]="{blocked: icon == blockedIcon}">
        <img src="assets/icons/{{trialNum+1}}/{{icon}}" [ngClass]="{blocked: icon == blockedIcon, selected: icon == selectedIcon}">
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="horizontal-divider">
<div class="commands-container">
    <button (click)="startExperiment()" [disabled]="started">Start experiment</button>
    <button (click)="getNextSet()" [disabled]="!started">Next set</button>
</div>
```

I searched for solutions on Stack Overflow and tried implementing what I found but for some reason it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the elements side by side, you should use style "display: inline-block".

And you can try wrap the content with a div and put a border layout at bottom like this:

**UPDATE**
Wrap the containers in a div with style display: grid; grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;

```css
        div.describer {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
}

div.describer div.container {
    margin: 1em;
}

div.describer div.container img.blocked {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

div.describer div.container img.target {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

div.guesser {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
}

div.guesser div.container {
    margin: 1em;
}

div.guesser div.container.blocked {
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.guesser div.container.blocked img.blocked {
    opacity: 0;
}

div.guesser div.container img.selected {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 3;
}

div.vertical-divider {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 20%;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

hr.horizontal-divider {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 19%;
}

div.commands-container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
div.div-main {
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        overflow: auto;
}
div.grid-containers {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="describer">
    <h3>Describer</h3>
    <div class="grid-containers">
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let icon of icons">
        <img src="assets/icons/{{trialNum+1}}/{{icon}}" [ngClass]="{blocked: icon == blockedIcon, target: icon == targetIcon}">
        <p *ngIf="icon == blockedIcon">Blocked</p>
        <p *ngIf="icon == targetIcon">Target</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vertical-divider"></div>
<div class="guesser">
    <h3>Guesser</h3>
    <div class="grid-containers">
    <div class="container" [ngClass]="{blocked: icon == blockedIcon}">
        <img src="assets/icons/{{trialNum+1}}/{{icon}}" [ngClass]="{blocked: icon == blockedIcon, selected: icon == selectedIcon}">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="commands-container">
    <button (click)="startExperiment()" [disabled]="started">Start experiment</button>
    <button (click)="getNextSet()" [disabled]="!started">Next set</button>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't mention that it's always 4 divs because the amount of elements in `icons` is always 4. There's no need for the duplicate `<div class="container></div>"` due to ngFor inserting it 4 times as the amount of elements in `icons`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. So, you can use style display: grid, on class "guesser" and "describer". And the elements should have the style grid-column-start: 1 for odd elements and grid-column-start:2 for even elements.

Comment: Better, you can wrap the containers in a div with style display: grid;  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;